# github notification to nodeJS when master get a commit

Tags: node.js, github, notifications, github-api

Is it possible if my master branch in my github repo gets an update that my nodeJS server got a notification ? so i can do stuff with it ? like get the version tag and commit message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to go to your repo, and click through this sequence:

> Settings -> Webhooks & Services -> Add webhook

Then paste the url where github will submit data for each new commit. You can find examples of payload in [example](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#example-delivery).

Then implement the logic needed in the backend to work with info about new commits.